# How to use rate limiting in C#, ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, rate-limiting, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a problem with rate limiting. I implemented rate limiting in my ASP.NET Core 6 project. It was doing well. I checked on localhost and everything is fine, but there is an error in the general test.

It works well for people who log in with their own internet. But if several people are connected from one wifi router, if one person is blocked, all users of this wifi router are blocked. What can I do?

My code is as follows:

```
public static void ConfigureRateLimiting(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(option =>
        {
            option.EnableEndpointRateLimiting = true;
            option.StackBlockedRequests = false;
            option.HttpStatusCode = 429;
            option.RealIpHeader = "X-Real-IP";
            option.ClientIdHeader = "X-ClientId";
            option.GeneralRules = new List<RateLimitRule> {
                
                new RateLimitRule()
                {
                    Endpoint="*",
                    Period="1h",
                    Limit=5,
                }
            };
        });

    services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();

    services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();

    services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();

    services.AddSingleton<IProcessingStrategy, AsyncKeyLockProcessingStrategy>();

    services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
}
```

Comment: 5 limit in 1h is only for test

Comment: Sounds like that router has some proxy or other functionality that causes all the connected users to have the same ip address. If the ip addresses aren't unique, you cannot use ip- based rate limiting

Comment: how can i save ddos attack, if i don't use this way

Comment: Better configuration. 5 requests per hour doesn't make sense. DDOS will be thousands per second.

Comment: 1 h -> 5 req is for example. I used rate limit conf on nginx

Comment: Yes, I understand is just an example. But I'm trying to say it's a bad example. You need a better example. You need better settings.